# A word for "I'm foolishly making random choices"

Tags: single-word-requests

Given a set of possible actions, you randomly pick one with no reason whatsoever, because you're a fool.

> I did my exam by **randomly choosing** my answers.

A somewhat related word might be *babbling*, which suggests there is a foolish/nonsensical/dumb element in action. But babbling seems to be too focused on conversations rather than option-picking.

The question [Single word for random selection](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65303/single-word-for-random-selection?rq=1) doesn't have answers with the "foolish" element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like [*willy-nilly.*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/willy-nilly)

> in a careless way, without planning
>
> *They can't just spend money willy-nilly.*
>
> *Books lay scattered through the house willy-nilly.*

In your example, it might be worded: *I answered the exam questions willy-nilly.*

Comment: This is an excellent answer, though a trifle informal. One that perfectly expresses what's needed but not one perhaps to include in a serious historical essay: viz. 'Napoleon at the gates of Moscow was moving his horse artillery "willy-nilly" from place to place.' Works better with 'Since winning $20 million on the lottery Fred and Mabel would do their shopping willy-nilly'. Incidentally, did you know that if you lived in 'Flyover country' in the UK you would be living under a Motorway intersection. So much for 'countries divided by a common language'.

Answer (score 2):

I like "helter skelter" and "higgedly-piggedly," but "haphazardly" works, too.

Comment: Recently I asked for a suitable translation of the French word 'bêtement', and 'mindlessly' was the one I eventually accepted as being closest to the meaning I had in mind. Is that any good?

Comment: @WS2 I think so. That better matches the OP's intent (to insult the person's intelligence), while my three suggestions are more neutral.

Comment: @WS2 For what it's worth, I would translate 'bêtement' as 'foolishly' or 'stupidly'. 'Mindlessly' is a bit different. (Sorry for the off-topic comment.)

Comment: @adj7388  This was extensively discussed under my OP of that question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[capriciously](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/capricious)*:

> Impulsive and unpredictable; determined by chance, impulse, or whim

Capricious connotes more recklessness than foolishness, but the distinction may not be that important to you.

Comment: Yes, that is how Napoleon moved his horse artillery. (see my above comment to JLG)

Answer (score 0):

In other words "I am being a maverick" , since choosing randomly has an unpredictable outcome and doing so is being foolish enough.

Comment: Please, capitalize the beginning of a sentence and the pronoun, I. This is a site for lovers of English and presumably they (we) should know the basic rules of punctuation.